# I get [ [Object] ] when trying to get info from JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, fetch

I'm creating a Discord bot which gets data from API and sends as message. Here's API answer which I see in url (it's from a vocabulary):

```
[{"definitionsList":
    [
        {
            "definition_id":"4798", "article_id":"9592", "definition_no":"1", "verb":"0", "definition":"Super hero definition"
        }, {
            "definition_id":"4799", "article_id":"9592", "definition_no":"2", "verb":"0", "definition":"Second definition"
        }
    ],

    "proverb": [
        {
            "article_id":"9593", "article":"An article", "suffix":null
        }
    ]
}]
```

And what I get when I fetch this data:

```
[
  {
    definitionsList: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    proverbs: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
```

Here my JavaScript code:

```
fetch (`https://idontwantshowurl.com/vocabulary?search=${Word}`).then (Search_Result => {
    Search_Result.json ().then (Word_JSON => {
        if (true) {
            console.log (Word_JSON)
        }
    }).catch (Error_ => {
        console.log ('Error 404 Not Found')
        console.error (Error_)
    })
}).catch (Error_ => {
    console.log ('Error 404 Not Found')
    console.error (Hata)
})
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try logging the data like so `console.log(JSON.stringify(WORD_JSON))` and see what it shows

Comment: It's working, thank you so much!